# VB.Net DLLImport

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke, dllimport

I got a PL/I Dll and I'm trying to import the DLL into my VB.Net Application.
The first try worked but the program did quit without comment after a few calls.
And it is not possible to call these function twice from two different threads.
I get the result from the DLL in paramone. Any Ideas why this doesn't work right and how to get it to work?

```
<DllImport(("PLIDLL.dll"), CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Sub MYFUNC(ByVal LogonString As String, _
                              <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)> ByRef paramone As String, _
                              ByVal paramtwo As String)
    End Sub
```

If anything is unclear please ask.

Greetings Lim

PS: I already tried to rerewrite the PL/I Code so that it returns a String instead of the ByRef value. Same issue.

The Sub in PLI:

```
   MYFUNC: PROC(LOGONSTRING,PARAMONE,PARAMTWO) REORDER
          OPTIONS(FROMALIEN NODESCRIPTOR
                  BYADDR LINKAGE(STDCALL));

          DEFAULT RANGE(*) STATIC;


   DCL LOGONSTRING CHAR(30);
   DCL PARAMONE CHAR(2033);            
   DCL PARAMTWO CHAR (5500);
```

Comment: Solved the issue that it gets called twice. Still the program does quit after a few calls.

Comment: We cannot help you until you show the other side of the interface. Clearly your side of the interface is wrong. There's nothing I've ever seen that matches ByRef string. But we can't tell you what is right if we don't know what's on the other side of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Found at least a working solution.

```
Module NativeMethods

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Function LoadLibrary(ByVal lpFileName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Function GetProcAddress(ByVal hModule As IntPtr, ByVal procedureName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Function FreeLibrary(ByVal hModule As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

End Module


<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Private Delegate Sub MYFUNC(ByVal LogonString As String, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)> ByRef PARAMONE As String, ByVal PARAMTWO As String)

Public Shared Sub CallFunction(ByRef workingObject As PLIOBJECT)
    Dim EntryPointer As IntPtr = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary("PLIDLL.dll")
    Dim FunctionPointer As IntPtr = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(EntryPointer, "MYFUNC")
    Dim MyFUNC As MYFUNC= CType(Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(FunctionPointer, GetType(MYFUNC)), MYFUNC)
    MyFUNC(workingObject.Logonstring, workingObject.PARAMONE, workingObject.PARAMTWO)
    Dim result As Boolean = NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(EntryPointer)

End Sub
```

Comment: How can we comment? You only told us half of the story. And the code in the answer is just the same as that in the question. Except that the library is loaded and unloaded every time you call. Which hides your error rather than fixing it. And is incredibly wasteful. If you would do what I asked and show the other side of the interface then we could help.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry, I'm confused what other side of the Interface? I know that it's pretty much the same and it does waste resources.

Comment: The DLL worked for years without any problems in VB6. And the program itself doesn't contain much more than the DLL Call. So please tell me what i should post or what you mean with "other side".

Comment: It's an interface. Interfaces have two sides. You shown the calling side, the VB.net. The other side is the PLI DLL. If you show working VB6 code then we could infer the other side of the DLL from that. Personally I feel you should delete this answer and add clarifications to the question.

Comment: Now I'm just more confused. I already postet the PLI Sub Header in the Question. I can't post the full PLI function that's simply impossible. And I didn't write the VB6 Code it just has to work in VB.Net until we get the time to rewrite the whole thing in VB.NET. @DavidHeffernan

Comment: So this is a working solution for my problem at the moment, no need to delete it for now because it simply works. I know it's not pretty and I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: You should delete it because it's no use to anybody else. Unless some insight comes out of this, such a gross hack isn't helpful for future visitors.